# Installing 3 Gang Smart Switch

Tags: smart-switch

I am installing 3 Kasa Tp link smart switches in one box. After installing, two fixtures work and one fixture just blinks on and off constantly. Original installation had a dimmer on this switch with only two black lines coming out of the dimmer. I swapped a kasa smart dimmer and a regular smart switch and they both have that blinking problem while the other two switches work fine.

I will attach a very rudimentary drawing lol. Since originally the line going to the dining room light didn’t have a neutral I just tied in with the neutral line on the other lines.

Thank you everyone for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### You can't do that

The dining room, and kitchen, circuits are old-school **switch loops**.  They only bring always-hot and switched-hot to the box.

You are poaching neutral from a different cable potentially on a different circuit or even different phase.  Can't do it.

You can't attach the smart-switch wires to anything except wires in that same cable.  All related wires must be in the same cable or conduit, NEC 300.3.  There are several reasons, but one relates to the current imbalance it causes, resulting in EMFs not canceling each other out as they normally would.

That means you will need to either go with a different smart switch, or use a smart module up at the lamp itself if power enters there.

As far as the blinking problem, it might be tangled up in this, but it might also be a problem of the light or bulb not being dimmer-ready. Try swapping an old-school incandescent in there and see if that fixes it; if so it's the bulb.

Comment: Thank you for your response. All of the lines in that box are on the same circuit. I also made sure I put a dimmable bulb in the fixture. I have to look into EMF’s - that’s all new to me lol. I just thought it would be ok to piggy back in the other neutrals. 

Most likely will just replace all 3 switches with a smart switch that does not require a neutral.

Comment: So I got a dimmer that doesn’t require a neutral. Installed that. And now the kitchen light is blinking. I am so confused. The kitchen light has been working until I went to put it in that dimmer.

Comment: @ArthurTobin It's possible that LED won't play nice with any dimmer, and will need to be changed to one that does.